# Query records with date greater than 60 days

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to query all records that have a date that is greater than 60 days of its created date and also has a null value in another field "Invoice#" The "Date_Created" field is saved as a date in YYYY-MM-DD. This is currently hat I am using but doesn't seem to be working. I get an error saying "Invoice_Number" is an unknown column and when I remove that part of the code I get nothing returned.

> select * from PO_Information where Date_Created >= (Date_Created +
>   Interval 60 day) and Invoice_Number IS NULL

Comment: try with Date_Created >= DATE_ADD(DateCreated, INTERVAL 60 day)

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE Date_Created >= DATE_ADD(Date_Created,INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

For the interval, but This will always return false, this is why you are getting no results when you remove the `IS NULL`

as for the unknown column, you have not told us about the table structure so I can't help you there